# Binary Tree Class Constructor

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I started working on some code to invert a binary tree and I got the below. It's pretty straightforward, but I didn't understand what is the "TreeNode() {}" iin the commented section accomplishing? Thank you!

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a no-argument constructor.

Comment: What is its purpose in the code? It has no arguments, but it also has no body

Comment: RIght, so it constructs a `TreeNode` object and its properties retain their default values, which is `null` for `left` and `right`, and `0` for `val`.

Comment: Ok - so it is just initializing the TreeNode for the definition that is about to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeNode() {}` is a no-argument constructor (which, in Java, is [different from a default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488766/7431860)). It has no body, and therefore accomplishes nothing. Since Java [initializes all member variables to their default values upon creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/268909/7431860), before the constructor is even invoked, the blank constructor body will leave these values in their default state.

Note that [since Objects are initialized to null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/268848/7431860), attempting to access `left` or `right` before assigning them will result in an error.

Comment: Thanks - this is great! I guess I'm still a little confused as to what is the need to include that, i.e. why include code that doesn't accomplish anything?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48553000/7431860) and its answers for a bit more info on why one might include a no-arg constructor in their class.