# Confusion between default constructor and no argument constructor(non default constructor)

Tags: java, constructor

```
class Cat{
    String name;
    int age;

    Cat(){
        String name = "Tom";
        int age = 3; 
    }
}
```

I have a confusion about if Cat() is a default constructor or a no argument constructor(non default constructor).I just want to that here **Cat()** is a default constructor or a no argument constructor(non default constructor)?

Comment: Since you have written it it cannot be the default constructor.

Comment: I understand you confusion. I pretty often see a no-arg constructor referred to as *default constructor*, which it isn’t if it’s a declared  constructor. The opposite is true, though: a default construcotr is generated automatically by the compiler and never takes argument, that is, it is a no-arg constructor.

Comment: Perhaps also related: [What is the purpose of a no-arg constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553000/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-no-arg-constructor)